# How to recover Ubuntu from changes made to files in gnome-shell/theme/

Tags: boot, gnome, gnome-shell, restore, gnome-shell-extension

I had made changes to file

```
usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css
```

And

```
usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

to decrease space between icons in app list. But, my system is now broken and after restart, I can't boot into Ubuntu.

I can go to recovery mode and access my terminal and grub is available too. I am using 20.04. How do I reverse those changes and properly boot into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reinstall the packages which provide [these](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-classic.css&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any) [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=Yaru%2Fgnome-shell-theme.gresource&searchon=contents) - backup and reinstall:

1. Backup:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css ~/
   cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource ~/
   ```
2. Reinstall:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extensions yaru-theme-gnome-shell
   ```
3. Then reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I repaired my Ubuntu 20.04.